# Unmarshal xml List Using xstream without setting aliases

Tags: java, xml, xstream, unmarshalling

I'm trying to unmarshal an xml document that contains lists of composite elements. Is it possible to do this without having to set the aliases individually for the list and the composit element.

the xml I'm consuming looks something like this:

```
 <Library>
    <Books>
            <Book>
            <author>author1</author>
            <title>title1</title>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <author>author2</author>
            <title>title2</title>
        </Book>
    </Books>
 <!-- other things here -->
</Library>
```

I have made the appropriate classes to correctly model the data

and using xstream

```
 XStream stream = new XStream();
    stream.alias("Library",Library.class);
    stream.alias("Book",Book.class);
    stream.alias("Books",List.class);
    Library lib = stream.fromXML(xml);
```

I am trying to avoid having to alias book to book.class and books to list.class

is this even possible or do I need to find a workaround of some sort?

Comment: "I have made the appropriate classes to correctly model the data" - but you've forgotten to include them in the question...

Comment: @IanRoberts I wasn't actually modelling books and libraries it was just an example since the actual object model is much more complex

Comment: Sorry, I didn't spot the fact that this question was 7 months old...